# How can I access WMS service from Geoserver using ArcGIS Silverlight API?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, wms, arcgis-silverlight-api

Having GeoServer installed locally in my machine, I'm currently doing a R&D by trying to access WMS service from GeoServer using ArcGIS API for Silverlight.

I'm trying to replicate the sample in ESRI site which deals with accessing a WMS service using ArcGIS API for Silverlight. I'm unable to view the map in the browser.

Given below is the XAML code used in my application:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApp.Beginners.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"     
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"     
  xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <esri:Map WrapAround="True">     
            <esri:WmsLayer 
              ID="OtherWMSLayer" 
              Layers="OSOpenData" 
              Url="http://localhost:9595/geoserver/wms" 
              Opacity="0.7" 
              SupportedSpatialReferenceIDs="4326"     
              SkipGetCapabilities="True" 
              Version="1.1" />
        </esri:Map>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Please can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: WMSLayer is defined in ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.Datasource http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18836-WMS-layer-in-Silverlight-app

Comment: On June 1, 2016 the ArcGIS API for Silverlight entered the retired phase of its product life cycle. ref https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/.