# How to include WMS, WMTS and WFS services using ArcGIS for Server Silverlight Builder?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, wfs, arcgis-silverlight-api, wmts

I am new to ArcGIS for server (silverlight builder) and I want to include public WFS, WMS and/or WMST services in an application I'm building but I just can't seem to do it.

I have read that ESRI is only supporting Bing, OpenStreetMap and services from ESRI online, as basemaps but surely it should be possible to use other services as layers within a application. Is it possible that ArcGIS for server uses a totally different REST interface and therefore wont recognise the URL endpoints I have tried?.

If something like this is the case is it possible to use a proxy to translate to and from ESRI speak??.

Comment: duplicate? - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33309/how-can-i-access-wms-service-from-geoserver-using-arcgis-silverlight-api

Comment: did you check the ArcGIS forums? Does this thread help: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18836-WMS-layer-in-Silverlight-app

Comment: Yes the thread was useful, thanks for that.However, what I'm really hopeing for is a way that user can do this without having to change configuration files. Is this possbile?

Comment: I don't think so. Otherwise, you can add a WMS layer by compiling an add-in for that: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-viewer/samples/start.html (search under Toolkit > Add WMS Layer)